# Deploying to an existing database from VS 2010 on TFS

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, source-control

I am trying to find a way in VS2010 to add a few objects to an existing database without scripting out all of the existing objects. This is a maintenance project that is adding a table, altering an existing table by adding a column, creating a foreign key constraint between them and altering a stored proc to use a new column in the existing table rather than a hard coded case statement. I tried a database project and then converted it to SSDT in an attempt to find a way to not drop the database.

The scripts generated from this database project generate drop and create statements for the database. If I manually remove the database portion of the scripts, the result is exactly what I need.  Is there a way to force the project to NOT drop and recreate the database, or is there a project type I can use instead?

Comment: Do you mean VS 2010? If so, are you using SSDT projects or one of its previous incarnations?

Comment: vs 2010 on TFS.  Tried both.

Comment: Tried both what? Also, what do you mean by "my project is just a couple of tables..."? An SSDT database project represents a database in its entirety. If you create a project containing two tables and try to publish to an existing database, it will want to drop all tables in the target that don't exist in the source.

Comment: Trying to find a way in VS2010 to add a few objects to an existing database without scripting out all of the existing objects.  This is a maintenance project that is adding a table altering an existing table creating a foreign key constraint between them and altering a stored proc to use a new column in the existing table rather than a hard coded case statement.  I tried a database project and then converted it to SSDT in an attempt to find a way to not drop the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SSDT, when you choose Publish to generate a script the advanced options include "Always re-create database". Untick that and you're good to go.

[image: Advanced Publish Settings]

Same option applies if you do a local debug build.

[image: Debug]

Similar options buried in the old VS2010 Database Project options somewhere.

To be honest, from the description of what you're doing SSDT and/or VS2010 database projects are overkill. Scribble a script in SSMS and be done with it.

Comment: Thanks, however that box is not checked on my project...  Guess I will just fall back to the script like you suggest.

Comment: You were right.  I was publishing against a local db which did not have the database, so it added drop/create statements for the db.  When I published against a test server with the proper db already there, it generated an incremental change script.  Thanks,